# query optimisation rank operator

Tags: sql, oracle, join, window-functions, rank

can some one please help me to optimize below query as it is taking long time to execute.

I tried to dugout the bottleneck and came with the analysis that there is no join between Table 2 and Table 3, and we need to use columns of table 2 and table 3 in the rank function which is impacting the performance. sad part of the story is that Table 2 and table 3 does not have relationship in between and cannot be joined.

Just to add, we can join table 1 with table 2, and output of this can be joined with table 3(table 1 has reference with both table 1 and table 2)

below is the table structures for reference ,hope it helps :

```
Table 1

Col1    Col2    Col3


Table 2

Col1_prnT   Col2_child


Table 3 

Col1_Prnt   Col2_Child
```

Table 2 and Table 3 cannot be joined,and we can join table 1 and table 2 as : `col1 =col2_prnt`
and table 1 and table 3 as `col1 =col1_prnt or col1 =col2_child.`

```
SELECT Table1.CEASE_DT,
       RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Table1.COL1
                   ORDER BY
            Table1.END_DT DESC,
            Table1.LST_DT DESC,
            Table2.END_DT DESC,
            Table2.LST_DT DESC,
            Table3.END_DT DESC,
            Table3.LST_DT DESC
            NULLS LAST
       ) AS RANK1
FROM Table1, Table2, Table3
WHERE
             ( (Table1.COL1=Table2.col1_prnt
                    AND 
                    Table2.COUNTRY_CD='XX'
                    ) 
                    OR  (Table1.COL1=Table3.COL1_CHILD
                    AND Table3.COUNTRY_CD='XX'
                    ) OR (Table1.COL1=Table3.COL1_PRNT
                    AND Table3.COUNTRY_CD='XX'
                        ))
```

Comment: have you put indexes on these columns?

Comment: The logic behind the joins is part of the business logic you need to implement. If you're not sure about this, please explain the logic you need and ask for help in efficiently implementing it. Assuming that your query is correct, it would be useful to know the complete structure of your tables ( including indexes), the number of records in each table and the explain plan of you query. Can you please post these informations? Also, please consider switching to ANSI SQL join syntax, instead of the old Oracle syntax.

Comment: `WHERE` with `AND` / `OR` are usually tricky to optimise , please put as much informations as you can

Comment: thanks for your answers, I am able to optimize the query